# Plotting 3d graphs in SAS University Edition

Tags: sas, sas-studio

I'm using SAS University edition and I'm trying to find a way to output 3d graphs. I know about the procedures:

```
g3d
g3grid
```

However they are not available in my SAS edition, and I was looking for something similar with no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I could workaround this and managed to do it using a template and `overlay3d`:

```
proc template;
  define statgraph surface;
  begingraph;
    layout overlay3d;
      surfaceplotparm x=gxc y=gyc z=estimate;
    endlayout;
  endgraph;
end;
run;

proc sgrender data=input template=surface;
run;
```

Comment: Just a note that SAS UE doesn't support any of the GPLOT/G proc but it does support the SG procedures - i.e. sgrender/sgplot. In my opinion they're better graphics :). You should mark you question answered.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably quite a bit more work than using `g3d`/`g3grid`, but you could create a scatter plot with separate series for each band of your z-axis variable, giving each series a different colour. You could use `proc sgplot` or `proc sgscatter` to do this.